# Find out if resolution on mac os x is HiDPI or not (via command-line)

Tags: macos, command-line

I am using the screencapture (/usr/sbin/screencapture) tool to make screenshots in Mavericks on a MacBook Pro with Retina. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
DATETIME=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
DEST=/Users/sasa/Pictures/Screenshots/screenshot-$DATETIME.png
CMD=/usr/sbin/screencapture
if [[ $1 = "area" ]]; then
  $($CMD -i $DEST)
elif [[ $1 = "window" ]]; then
  $($CMD -wo $DEST)
elif [[ $1 = "screen" ]]; then
  $($CMD -m $DEST)
fi

convert $DEST -resize 50% $DEST.new # halve the image
mv -f $DEST.new $DEST
```

Since I switch through display resolutions regularly I only want to call `convert $DEST -resize 50% $DEST.new` if a HiDPI resolution is active.

Explanation: If you take a screenshot in HiDPI mode with resolution 1680x1050 HiDPI the resulting images will be 3360x2100px. In this case I want to halve it.

All the tools I tried so far, will not give me this simple information.

- xdpyinfo
- screenresolution (https://github.com/jhford/screenresolution)
- system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType

Any ideas?